# How to check if a value in a Vec is None?

Tags: loops, rust, vector

I would like to use the fact that `Vec.last()` returns a `None` if there is nothing at that index but that index still exists. The problem is that I can't find a way to compare the result to anything inside of a `while` or `if`. I can however compare it if I use `match`, although that seems less efficient than using a `while` loop. Is there a way to compare it in an `if` or a `while` loop?

This is what I'm trying to do, but the `self.particles.last() == None` is invalid since you can't compare things to `None` except `None` as far as I can tell.

```
while vec.last() == None {
    num += 1;
}
```

Comment: I think I found a workaround, although I don't know how good it is.

Comment: if match self.particles.last() {Some(_) => {false},None => {true}} {}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [`Option::is_none`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_none):

```
while vec.last().is_none() {
    ...
}
```

But that's boring. We're here to learn. Perhaps there's a convoluted, hard to read option where we can flex our Rust muscles? As it happens, there is! Let's take a look at one of my favorite Rust features, pattern matching.

What's that? Well, normally you'd write something like this, which loops as long we you get `Some` items and simultaneously binds the items to a variable:

```
while let Some(elem) = vec.last() {
    ...
}
```

`Some(elem)` is a pattern. It turns out that `None` fills the same syntactical role. It's a pattern, albeit one without a variable:

```
while let None = vec.last() {
    ...
}
```

I admit `let` without a variable looks odd, and it looks like it's backwards having the `None` on the left, but it works.

(Also, I should point out this will be an infinite loop if you don't modify `vec`.)

Comment: Using a pattern matching instead of `is_none()` here just to be enough cool is bad.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Could you explain why it is bad, please?

Comment: Because it's overusing a clever technique when a simple one is available. It's nice, I don't argue (and you can also use `matches!()`), but not worth it.

Comment: I agree that's it's not practical, just a fun diversion. I wouldn't actually use it here. I've edited my answer to make that crystal clear. :)

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to use the fact that `Vec.last()` returns a `None` if there is nothing at that index but that index still exists.

You seem to be very confused about the behaviour of `Vec::last`. It's absolutely not going to return `None` if "that index still exists" (whatever that means). It's going to return `None` if the vec is empty, that's it.

So your loop is either never going to execute, or will loop forever.

> This is what I'm trying to do, but the self.particles.last() == None is invalid since you can't compare things to None except None as far as I can tell.
>
> ```rust
> while vec.last() == None {
>     num += 1;
> }
> ```

No? The issue would probably be that `Option<T>` is `PartialEq` iff `T` is `PartialEq`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=00f4ea97a0fad1cd74ef3b6ac6b74dc8

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Equatable;
struct NonEquatable;
fn main() {
    // compiles fine
    println!("{}", None == Some(Equatable));
    // can't compile
    // println!("{}", None == Some(NonEquatable));
}
```

Though it is obviously not the normal way to do it, you'd usually use [`Option::is_none`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_none), possibly [`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) in some rare cases (but that's more for enums which don't have predicates).